# What’s “maiden name” all about?

Tags: word-choice, british-english

I was pondering the term *maiden name* when talking with British English speakers recently. They don’t seem to have that term. So my question is two-fold:

1. Is there another term for *maiden name*, especially in British English?
2. Does anyone find *maiden* a little offensive? I mean, is it OK to call an unmarried woman a *maiden*?

Comment: I doubt many people find *maiden* offensive. It's just a bit dated/archaic. And apart from being a bit "la-di-dah", *née* isn't the same part of speech. I'm quite used to hearing people speak of "birth name" to get round those two problems.

Comment: Remember that [men can also have maiden names](http://www.nytimes.com/1995/05/14/magazine/about-men-my-maiden-name.html), and I don’t just mean whatever the maidens call them, either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Quoth Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:nee): “The masculine form, ***né***, is less common but is occasionally used to give the birth name of a man who has changed his name for some reason. *Née* and *né* are also used more generally to denote former names (as opposed to birth names), and earlier names of inanimate entities such as companies and products.” [And here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/né).

Comment: @tchrist: They simplified the rules and dramatically reduced the cost of [changing your name by Deed Poll](http://hmdeedpoll.org.uk/?gclid=CLev4sSx7rgCFaKWtAodmS0A9w) in the UK not long ago, and apparently the number of people doing this has skyrocketed in the last year or two. Probably lots of them are immigrants "Anglicising" their names. If I saw the form *né*, I'd probably assume that was the likely context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word "maiden" (at least in the UK) is now essentially an obsolete word. It's not that anyone would find it particularly offensive, so much as it's basically not used any more. (As with other obsolete words, it's occasionally used for irony, so you might jokingly refer to somebody as a "fair maiden", but the intent is humoristic rather than to cause offence.)

But, as is often the case, this obsolete word survives in the fixed phrase "maiden name", which is still perfectly common in British usage. I don't think anyone finds it offensive-- it's just an administrative term, and the word "maiden", offensive or not, is as I say to all intents and purposes no longer used anyway. People are generally familiar with the term because it's very very common for banks to ask you, for example, what your "mother's maiden name" is.

However, as English is an international language, now spoken by more non-native than native speakers, there's also a move to try and avoid obscure terms, or deliberately choose alternatives whose meaning is more obvious to speakers of other languages. So it's possible we may see a move towards alternatives such as "Family name before you were married".

Comment: We can still bowl a maiden over.

Comment: Especially with my wit and charm

Comment: @Barrie: I'm not sure I could!

Comment: I can't speak for other English-speaking countries, but this answer goes for the USA as well.

Comment: Hair metal bands may be a thing of the past, but I wouldn't say that *Maiden* is obsolete.  Where would we be without hits like "Run to the Hills"?

Comment: I believe maiden was used to imply virgin, when that was more nearly synonymous with unmarried, and what happened was that maidenhood itself became (more or less) obsolete. The obsolescence of the word merely followed.

Comment: "Maiden name" is far from obsolete; any time it needs to be used, it is used. It's just one of those words that doesn't come up very often.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: I quite agree it's by no means *obsolete*, but it does hover somewhere between *dated* and *archaic* outside a few idiomatic compound usages.

Comment: @mickeyf. Just to confirm your comment, let me add that the MED (Middle English Dictionary - Univ Mich.) has an entry for *meiðlure* as "loss of virginity, fornication" - ca. 1230 - where *meið* is the adjective "of a maiden" and lore "loss, destruction". See also Alfred Bammesberger and Joachim Grzega (2001) on the much vexed question of the etymology of *girl* and that of *maiden*, *maid*, *ides* (woman, wife, virgin, lady, queen) and *scielcen* (female servant).

Comment: @Alain If I'd been on my toes I'd have said not that maidenhood, but that maidenheads became obsolete...

Answer (score 8):

In written (esp. formal) English the term "née" (literally, born) is used to denote the surname at birth, e.g Barbara Smith née Jones.

Maiden name is definitely alive and well and in use in Britain, as Neil said - mother's maiden name is a very common 'security' question for banks. I'd also agree maiden is very archaic used on its own.

Comment: On that note, I've always found people in the sub-continent answer that question as "Barbara" and not "Jones". Is that a common mistake or does that never happen in the UK?

Comment: Never say never! But I'd say that it would be very uncommon for a native BE speaker to confuse given/first/christian name (all of which can be used to refer to the 'Barbara' part of the name) for maiden name.

Comment: [Quoth Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:nee): “The masculine form, ***né***, is less common but is occasionally used to give the birth name of a man who has changed his name for some reason. *Née* and *né* are also used more generally to denote former names (as opposed to birth names), and earlier names of inanimate entities such as companies and products.”

Answer (score 3):

Oh yes, we do, but it's perhaps a little archaic. Alternatives might be 'unmarried name' or 'name before you were married'. Others will have to say whether it's offensive or not, but changing patterns of marriage and cohabitation make it seem less relevant than it once was.

Answer (score 3):

"Maiden name" may sound archaic, but it still functions better than "birth name," because the latter assumes that you have had the same surname since birth.  This is not true in my case; my mother married when I was two and my legal name was changed along with hers. Given that my biological father was a deadbeat and that my stepfather is a wonderful person, I take issue with people calling my current name my "birth name."

Answer (score 2):

A maiden is an "unmarried" woman. Therefore, a woman's "maiden name" is her "unmarried" (last) name, the one she received from her father.

A woman's married name is the one she receives from her husband. Some women nowadays do not take their husband's surname, and therefore continue to use their "maiden" name.

Women are seldom referred to as maidens anymore (except in jest), but as a qualifier to "name," the term has "stuck."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you got that impression. The term is very much alive and well and is the standard terminology for a married woman's surname pre-dating her marriage.

However, the degree to which some people don't recognise their own language can be staggering at times.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your two:

Technically "maiden" refers to whether the young lady in question has experienced sexual intercourse before or not. Perhaps there was a day when this was very salient information in social situations, but today is not such a day.

Use of the word by itself to refer to a female would carry the implication that you consider the woman's past sexual history your business, which it almost certianly *is not*. So it really should be avoided in all but the most unusual of cases.

The term "Maiden Name" can be considered one of those cases. It is fairly safe to assume that at *some* point (birth at least), every woman qualified, so it is fairly reasonable as a shorthand to refer what their name was at that point in the indeterminate past.

Comment: I disagree: *maiden* and *virgin* are not exact synonyms. In particular, *maiden* just means "never married"; it doesn't, on its own, refer to sexual experience — that's merely an assumption that could be made based on societal mores. Objecting to the word *maiden* on the grounds that "it's none of anyone's business" goes way beyond *overly sensitive* and into the realm of *utterly ridiculous*.

Comment: The OED’s definition 2a is ‘a virgin’, with the qualification ‘now rare’.

Comment: @Marthaª - I'm sorry, but you have that exactly backwards. Maiden originally meant "virgin", and came to be used for "never married" based on societal expectations about sex and marriage.